# Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous for 3 tables Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am currently doing a system. In the system, there's a module called manage resident; where the manage resident will get the information of the resident if it is single, married and have a child(first,middle and last name for example).

I've done the adding or create new resident part, I am now in edit resident part. When I click the edit resident, I encountered error

> Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous

I have 3 tables: resident, married and children. Resident ID is the foreign key of married, while Married ID is the foreign key of children table.

My data example for each table(column Primary key, foreign key, first_name, middle_name, last_name

```
Resident -> id, Testing, Testing, Testing
Married  -> Married_id, resident_id, Testing, Testing, Testing
Children -> id, married_id, Testing, Testing, Testing
```

Question: How can I get the children of the selected Resident? Then display it separately in my fields in my view.

**Controller**

```
 $id = $this->uri->segment(4);
 $get_children = $this->Crud_model->get_children($id);
```

**Model**

```
public function get_children($id){
        $this->db->select('*');    
        $this->db->from('resident');
        $this->db->where('id',$id);
        $this->db->join('married', 'resident.id = married.resident_id');
        $this->db->join('children', 'resident.id = children.married_id');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->row();
    }
```

**View**

```
 <?php $explode = explode(",",$children->first_name); ?>

<div class="form-group">
  <label>First Name</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="child_fname" id="child_fname"><?= $explode?>
</div>
```

Comment: `$this->db->where('id',$id);` change `id` to `resident.id`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Whenever you join tables with where condition you should write each column with its reference table name.

so change

```
$this->db->where('id',$id);
```

to

```
$this->db->where('resident.id',$id);
```

Comment: I just tried it, it's NULL. I also tried to var_dump the id. Im getting the value of 2

Comment: try to print your query. `$this->db->last_query();`

Comment: When I tried to display it in my view I am getting "Array to string conversion" . In my add new resident, I used implode to get the array(for example the resident have 2 children) then save it in my table. I used explode to separate the 2 children(For Example abcd,efgh).

Comment: try `echo "<pre>": print_r($your_array_variable);`

Comment: Display the data and when I tried to pre/var_dump it have vaues

Comment: so just use `foreach` in your view and show the data as you want to display.

Comment: @urfusion if I used $this->db->where('resident.id',$id); then giving duplicate prefix issue in codeigniter 4. Any solution for it?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this solution for your problem:

> Query:

```
public function get_children($id){
   $this->db->select('*');    
   $this->db->from('resident');
   $this->db->where('resident.id',$id);
   $this->db->join('married', 'resident.id = married.resident_id', 'left');
   $this->db->join('children', 'resident.id = children.married_id','left');
   $query = $this->db->get();
   return $query->row();
}
```

I Hope it will help you.